# java.io.IOException on reading class with arabic name

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, cucumber-jvm

after upgrade to Android Studio2.2preview and gradle plugin 2.2alpha2, I start getting below error with cucumber-java as one of the dependencies

```
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file '/mypath/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/androidTest/dev/jars/3/1f/main.jar'.
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file '/mypath/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/androidTest/dev/jars/3/1f/main.jar'.
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:404)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:348)
        at com.android.builder.files.IncrementalRelativeFileSets.fromZip(IncrementalRelativeFileSets.java:105)
        at com.android.builder.files.IncrementalRelativeFileSets.fromZip(IncrementalRelativeFileSets.java:84)
        at com.android.builder.files.IncrementalRelativeFileSets.fromZipsAndDirectories(IncrementalRelativeFileSets.java:258)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:291)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.doFullTaskAction(PackageApplication.java:73)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read directory entry index 5072 (total directory bytes read: 558556).
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.CentralDirectory.makeFromData(CentralDirectory.java:233)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZFile.readCentralDirectory(ZFile.java:650)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZFile.readData(ZFile.java:472)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZFile.<init>(ZFile.java:399)
        ... 74 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read stored entry 'cucumber/api/java/ar/اذاً.class'.
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.CentralDirectory.readEntry(CentralDirectory.java:359)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.CentralDirectory.makeFromData(CentralDirectory.java:230)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read data descriptor record.
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.StoredEntry.<init>(StoredEntry.java:274)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.CentralDirectory.readEntry(CentralDirectory.java:357)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incorrect value for field 'CRC32': value is 24904624 but 310353179 expected.
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.ZipField.verify(ZipField.java:209)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.StoredEntry.readDataDescriptorRecord(StoredEntry.java:475)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.zip.StoredEntry.<init>(StoredEntry.java:272)
        ... 79 more
```

Looks like it's not reading arabic, I have also set below

```
compileOptions {
    encoding "UTF-8"
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

but still no luck

Comment: Is that the entirety of the stack trace? If not, please add it all.

Comment: Hi @AndyTurner, full stack added. Proguard was on also.

Comment: Looks like a new 2.2-alpha2 proguard file is automatically generated using new plugin, could that be an issue?

Comment: Seems like a bug. I had the same problem. I've reported it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the Gradle plugin, they already fixed it and and the fix will be available in the next release (rc1). Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221057

Comment: I've detected one library which has symbols `\`` and `ˊ` as field names. I just remove it from my dependencies and ProGuard works well now. This is `upalytics.com` library. I just wanna to look in the eyes of those assholes.

Answer (score 0):

According to niqueco answer:
in project level build.gradle use gradle plugin version 2.2.3.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
```

}

Restart Android studio and it should works